# Incorrect FPS when muxing VP9-encoded data into .webm

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to mux some video data to a WebM file using FFmpeg. I specify a `time_base` through an `AVDictionary` (detailed below), but it appears that my specified `time_base` values are ignored by the muxer. Instead, it always uses a `time_base` of `1/1000`, and therefore an FPS of `1000`. My initialization code is below:

```
HRESULT WINAPI InitializeVideoEncoding(Encoder* encoder,
    LPCSTR codec, LPCSTR outputContainer, LPCSTR* options, UINT optCount)
{
    // Fill the options
    Log("Loading options.");
    for (UINT i = 0; i < optCount; ++i)
    {
        int opt = i * 2;
        const char* key = options[opt];
        const char* value = options[opt + 1];
        Log("Adding option %s: %s", key, value);
        if (av_dict_set(&encoder->options, key, value, 0) < 0)
        {
            Log("Failed to add item to dictionary: %s %s", key, value);
        }
    }

    // Make sure the encoder options aren't null when they should have
    // been filled.
    if (!encoder->options && optCount > 0)
    {
        Log("Failed to initialize encoder options.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Grab the buffer size early and remove it from the dict so we don't
    // get complaints from FFmpeg
    {
        const char* frameBufKey = "frame_buf_size";
        encoder->ioBufSize = 131072;
        AVDictionaryEntry* e = av_dict_get(encoder->options,
                                            frameBufKey,
                                            NULL, 0);
        if (e)
        {
            // Set the value and remove from the list.
            encoder->ioBufSize = strtol(e->value, NULL, 10);
            av_dict_set(&encoder->options, frameBufKey, NULL, 0);
        }
    }

    // Create the output context
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&encoder->outputFormatContext, NULL, outputContainer, NULL);
    if (!encoder->outputFormatContext)
    {
        Log("Couldn't create output format context.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    encoder->outputFormat = encoder->outputFormatContext->oformat;

    // Create the output stream
    encoder->outputStream = avformat_new_stream(encoder->outputFormatContext, NULL);
    if (!encoder->outputStream)
    {
        Log("Couldn't create output stream.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    encoder->outputStream->id = encoder->outputFormatContext->nb_streams - 1;

    // Find the codec
    encoder->codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec);
    if (!encoder->codec)
    {
        Log("Couldn't find encoder.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Create the encoding context
    encoder->encodingContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder->codec);
    if (!encoder->encodingContext)
    {
        Log("Couldn't create encoding context.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Set the basics
    encoder->encodingContext->width = encoder->width;
    encoder->encodingContext->height = encoder->height;

    // Open the codec
    int result = avcodec_open2(encoder->encodingContext, encoder->codec, &encoder->options);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        LogFFmpegError(result, "Couldn't open codec.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    if (av_dict_count(encoder->options) > 0)
    {
        // Dump the fields we didn't fill
        char* dictEntryBuf;
        av_dict_get_string(encoder->options, &dictEntryBuf, ':', ',');

        Log("The following provided options were unused:\n%s", dictEntryBuf);

        av_freep(&dictEntryBuf);
    }

    // Set some params afterwards
    encoder->outputStream->time_base = encoder->encodingContext->time_base;

    if (encoder->outputFormat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        encoder->encodingContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    // Copy necessary information to the stream
    result = avcodec_parameters_from_context(encoder->outputStream->codecpar,
                                             encoder->encodingContext);

    if (result < 0)
    {
        LogFFmpegError(result, "Couldn't copy stream parameters.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    av_dump_format(encoder->outputFormatContext, 0, NULL, 1);

    // Initialize IO callbacks
    encoder->ioBuf = (LPBYTE)av_malloc(encoder->ioBufSize);
    Log("Encoder IO buffer size: %d", encoder->ioBufSize);

    AVIOContext* ioContext = avio_alloc_context(encoder->ioBuf,
                                                (int)encoder->ioBufSize,
                                                1,
                                                encoder,
                                                NULL,
                                                WriteStreamCallback,
                                                NULL);
    encoder->outputFormatContext->pb = ioContext;

    result = avformat_write_header(encoder->outputFormatContext, NULL);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        LogFFmpegError(result, "Couldn't write header.");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

You'll notice the `time_base` is not manually specified. Instead, I'm using the built-in dictionary functionality so I can control these parameters without having to recompile the program. The values I'm pass in are below:

```
const char* params[] =
{
    "frame_buf_size", "131072",
    "b", "2000000",
    "time_base", "1:15",
    "pixel_format", "yuv420p",
    "speed", "6",
    "tile-columns", "4",
    "frame-parallel", "1",
    "threads", "8",
    "static-thresh", "0",
    "deadline", "realtime",
    "lag-in-frames", "0",
    "error-resilient", "1"
};
```

I did some investigating, and the `time_base` of my output stream is `1/15` right up until `avformat_write_header` is called. It appears that something inside this function call is changing the time base.

Now, I read in the FFmpeg mailing lists that WebM requires a `time_base` of `1/1000`, and I believe this is why the WebM avformat_write_header implementation rewrites the value of `time_base` for the stream. I may be mistaken, but the frame rate is tied to the time-base, and a frame rate of 1000 fps is simply too large for the video player I'm using to test this (specifically, a media extensions player in a web browser).

I'm aware that the timestamp of a packet is important, so below is the code I'm using to give each packet a timestamp:

```
// somewhere I create a frame
encoder->yuvFrame->pts = encoder->nextPts++;

// somewhere I actually write to the muxer:
av_packet_rescale_ts(packet, encoder->encodingContext->time_base,
                    encoder->outputStream->time_base);
```

In short, no matter what `time_base` I specify, it appears the muxer will overwrite it with `1/1000`. Is this an issue with FFmpeg, or am I missing some initialization steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, the outputted video file from my application was in fact valid. As per the answer by R.., the `1/1000` figure was required and enforced by the WebM muxer, and was not something I should be changing. Instead, I had to manually set the frame rate of my `AVCodecContext` and the average frame rate of my `AVStream`. This wrote the necessary information in the WebM header and allowed my video to be played back in the test player.

```
encoder->outputStream->time_base = encoder->encodingContext->time_base;

// Manually set the frame rate on the codec context
encoder->encodingContext->framerate = av_inv_q(encoder->encodingContext->time_base);

//Manually set the frame rate of the stream
encoder->outputStream->avg_frame_rate = encoder->encodingContext->framerate;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking but I'll try to provide some useful info.

What time bases are supported is a property of the format and/or codec you're using. If the format only supports 1/1000, that's what you have to use.

A time base of 1/1000 does not mean your video has to be 1000 fps. It means the timestamps you feed in need to be in units of 1/1000 of a second (i.e. milliseconds).

Simply compute millisecond timestamps for your 15fps frames before feeding them in. This computation should be as simple as:

```
timestamp = frame_number * 1000 / 15;
```

There may very well be a function in libav* to do this for you.

Comment: "There may very well be a function in libav* to do this for you."

I believe this is what `av_packet_rescale_ts` does, since the `pts` and `dts` values differ before and after calling `av_packet_rescale_ts`. `ffprobe` still reports the video is 1000fps though.